# Update SQL Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a sql table with column structure like below

```
Column1   | Column2
----------|----------
Texas     | Done
New York  | Cone
```

Now we want to update column2 text as "Texas Done". We just want to add column1 value before column2

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make this update for all your rows, you can use such `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET Column2 = CONCAT(Column1, ' ', Column2)
-- If you want only some of the rows updated, you can also add WHERE statement:
-- WHERE <some filtering conditions>
```

Comment: cant add strings in mysql, requires concat

Comment: @amdixon Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer